# How to add a custom Arabic and Persian font to chart.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm currently working with react-chartjs-2. My goal is to apply a custom font, which I have loaded in my CSS, to the charts created with chartjs. I have read the documentation, and while there is a code snippet for adding fonts in the options, it doesn't seem to work for me. Could you please advise me on how to change the font for all the charts?

```
plugins: {
    labels: {
        font: {
            family: "customFont",
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default like so: `Chart.defaults.font = 'customFont';`.

This will apply your custom font to all charts

Comment: Is this also working for React-chartjs-2?

Comment: Yes it does, you just need to import Chart from chart.js and then it works